# Select next location based on date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables one that has a begin date and ID :

```
Begin_Date                  ID
2015-12-14 00:00:00.0000000  1
2015-12-10 19:00:00.0000000  2
2015-12-09 19:00:00.0000000  3
2015-12-07 00:00:00.0000000  4
2015-12-06 00:00:00.0000000  5
```

The other table has associated locations for those records based on the ID:

```
DateAndTime                 ID
2015-12-14 00:00:00.0000000  1
2015-12-15 19:00:00.0000000  1
2015-12-16 19:00:00.0000000  1
2015-12-12 00:00:00.0000000  2
2015-12-13 00:00:00.0000000  2
```

I have a statement joining these two tables together but I am struggling to write the second half of this query. I want the query to select the first location available after or equal to the begin date. So for ID 1, the query would select `2015-12-14 00:00:00.0000000` from Table2. In most cases, the begin date in Table1 will be equal to the first DateAndTime available in Table2. But in other cases, the first location might be a day or two later. For example, the query would ideally select `2015-12-12 00:00:00.0000000  2` even though the begin date is `2015-12-10 19:00:00.0000000`

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT 
ST_GeogPoint(Longitude, Latitude) AS points,
Table1.ID
FROM `Table1` AS Table1 INNER JOIN 
`Table2` AS Table2 
ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID 
WHERE Table2.DateAndTime = Table1.BeginDate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.ID,
       ARRAY_AGG(ST_GeogPoint(Longitude, Latitude) ORDER BY t2.DateAndTime ASC LIMIT 1)[ORDINAL(1)] AS point
Table1.ID
FROM `Table1` t1 INNER JOIN 
     `Table2` AS Table2 
     ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t2.DateAndTime >= t1.BeginDate
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried running your code but got an error:  `Array element access with array[position] is not supported. Use array[OFFSET(zero_based_offset)] or array[ORDINAL(one_based_ordinal)] at [2:85]`

Comment: @james . . . There was a typo in the expression.